# Make Bootstrap Nav Sticky Top

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar, nav

I am making a website with Bootstrap and the navbar to stick to the top however using the class `sticky-top` doesn't seem to do anything.

Here is the code for the nav:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <ul class="nav justify-content-center sticky-top">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put `sticky-top` to the container of your navbar, if that `row` is the navbar, then you need to put it there instead of its child.

```css
/* For displaying */
body {
  height: 300vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, white, black);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- You need to move sticky-top to the outer element of navbar, which is here -->
<div class="row sticky-top">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <ul class="nav justify-content-center">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this explanation was the best I found and it works! ;)